# Program for entering 1000 random numbers into two different databases, one for odd numbers and one for even

Tags: java, performance, sql, mysql

I have created a program in java for entering 1000 random numbers into two different database one for odd numbers and one for even. The code is executing fine but it takes nearly a minute to execute. How can I minimize the execution time?

The source code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Random;

public class Test1 extends Thread {

public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

int evencount = 0;
int oddcount = 0;
int breakcon = 0;
int breakcon1 = 0;

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db1" + "?useSSL=false", "root",
        "1234");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db2" + "?useSSL=false", "root",
        "1234");

try {

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    for (int n = 1; n <= 1000; n++) {
        Random r = new Random();
        int val = r.nextInt(100000);

        if (val % 2 == 0) {
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(" insert into try values (?)");
            ps.setInt(1, val);
            ps.executeUpdate();
            ps.addBatch();
            breakcon = breakcon + 1;
            if (breakcon % 500 == 0 || breakcon == val)
                ps.executeBatch();
            evencount++;

        } else {
            try {

                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                PreparedStatement ps3 = conn.prepareStatement(" insert into try1 values (?)");
                ps3.setInt(1, val);
                ps3.executeUpdate();
                ps3.addBatch();
                breakcon1 = breakcon1 + 1;
                if (breakcon1 % 500 == 0 || breakcon1 == val)
                    ps3.executeBatch();

                oddcount++;

            }

            catch (Exception e2) {
                System.out.println(e2);
            }
        }
    }

}

catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}

long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00000");
System.out.println("Execution time is " + formatter.format((end - start) / 1000d) + " seconds");
System.out.println(oddcount + evencount);

}
}
```

Comment: Why do you enter the numbers into two different _databases_, as opposed to entering them into different _tables_ of the same database?

Answer (score 3):

**Structure your code**

- Name your variables appropriately! It is *not* a good idea to have the connections called `con` and `conn`. Likewise `ps` and `ps3` are not good names for your prepared statements. It will confuse you when trying to debug this.
- Make a *method* that inserts a value into a database.
- Do not catch `Exception`. Make sure you know what exception you catch and why. Right now you declare your `main` to throw exceptions, but I don't think it really does.

**Prepared statements are reusable**

You prepare a statement to let the database optimize for it. It takes a bit of time, but it saves time when you use it. What you do, is you prepare the statement *inside* your loop, making it a lot slower. Move the preparation of your statement

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into try values (?)");
```

*outside* your loop. This will make your program run faster.

**Random is reusable**

You create a new instance of `Random` on every rotation of the loop. Move this outside the loop - it will make your code run faster.

**Remove unnecessary things**

Your code is littered with statements executing expensive methods to no use.

What does

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

do?

What is the purpose of

```
ps.addBatch();
breakcon = breakcon + 1;
if (breakcon % 500 == 0 || breakcon == val)
  ps.executeBatch();
```

What is the purpose of `oddcount` and `evencount`?

Comment: Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver") used to be necessary with old versions of JDBC (before 4.0), but is no longer necessary

Comment: @jrtapsell Thank you, I didn't know. But how many times?

Comment: Only once, it registered the driver, now they use services instead

Comment: I added more explanation in an answer

Answer (score 3):

### Indentation

#### What is the problem?

Your code may have lost its indentation as it was uploaded, but as it shows above the indentation is missing.

#### Why is this a problem?

It makes reading and reasoning about how it works and what it does harder. It also makes it easier for bugs to hide in code.

#### How to fix

You want to indent your code, most IDEs and even some more basic text editors have the ability to do this automatically.

### Class.forName

#### What is the problem?

This used to be needed before JDBC4.0 (before Java 6), but now drivers are automatically loaded as services, so they do not need to be explicitly forced to load by the classloader.

#### Why is this a problem?

It forces a particular driver to be reloaded at that point, which wastes time, and adds confusion, it also adds the risk it will throw `ClassNotFoundException` in the future if the driver changes class name.

#### How to fix it

Remove this line
`Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`

### Unnecessary Extension

#### What is the problem?

The class extends `Thread`, but does not override the method `run`. You do not need to extend Thread for a single-threaded application, only if you need to make a thread that is extra to the main one.

#### Why is this a problem?

Even if an instance of this class was made and started, it would do nothing, so the class does not need to extend `Thread`

#### How to fix

Remove `extends Thread`

### Connections are not closed

#### What is the problem?

Connections extend `Autoclosable`, but are not closed

#### Why is this a problem?

It causes resource leaks

#### How to fix

Create the connections using [Try-With-Resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) syntax to ensure they are closed after use